# Xamarin.Forms iOS Project is not being loaded

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.forms

While downloaded some example project for images, my iOS project is not getting loaded and while reloading iOS project, I am getting below mentioned error in VS 2012.

**The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.**

Could anyone please help me out to resolve the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, but you'll need to manually edit your .csproj files and change `...\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets` to `...\Xamarin.MonoTouch.CSharp.targets`